# Dynamic looping on for each loop based on count using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file where I need to sum of count value based upon tag values
Now the tag values range from 0 - 800. I need to make the sum of count values based upon tag series like 0-100 on series, one sum of count for this series then for 100 -200 and so on.

Input XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<marcstats>
  <datafields>
    <field count="3519" tag="035">
      <subfields>
        <subfield code="a" count="3519" />
      </subfields>
    </field>
    <field count="4123" tag="100">
      <subfields>
        <subfield code="a" count="4123" position="" />
      </subfields>
    </field>
    <field count="3515" tag="101">
      <subfields>
        <subfield code="4" count="" position="" />
      </subfields>
    </field>
    <field count="4123" tag="200">
      <subfields>
        <subfield code="a" count="4123" />
        <subfield code="e" count="57" />
      </subfields>
    </field>
    <field count="181" tag="215">
      <subfields>
        <subfield code="a" count="181" />
      </subfields>
    </field>
    <field count="320" tag="300">
      <subfields>
        <subfield code="a" count="320" />
      </subfields>
    </field>
    <field count="2896" tag="330">
      <subfields>
        <subfield code="a" count="2896" />
      </subfields>
    </field>
```

The XSL that I have written so far:

```
<xsl:key name="tag" match="//field" use="@tag"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

  <chart>
    <categories>
      <xsl:call-template name="process-category">
      </xsl:call-template> 
    </categories>
    <xsl:call-template name="process-series">
      <xsl:with-param name="max">
        <xsl:for-each select="//field/@tag">
          <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" 
                    order="descending"/>
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template> 
  </chart>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-category">
  <item>100</item>
  <item>200</item>
  <item>300</item>
  <item>400</item>                          
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-series">
  <xsl:param name="max"/>
  <xsl:if test="//field[$endCount &lt; $max]">
    <series>
      <name>0xx</name>
      <data>
        <point><xsl:value-of 
          select="sum(//field
                  [@tag &gt; $startCount 
                  and @tag &lt; $endCount]/@count)"/></point>
      </data>
    </series>
  </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

But it is giving only for one series, How to achieve for all the series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="field-by-cat" match="field" use="@tag - @tag mod 100"/>

<xsl:variable name="max">
    <xsl:for-each select="/marcstats/datafields/field">
        <xsl:sort select="@tag" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="@tag"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
        <xsl:call-template name="summarize"/>
    </data>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="summarize">
    <xsl:param name="from" select="0"/>
    <xsl:param name="to" select="$from + 100"/>
    <point from="{$from}" to="{$to}">
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('field-by-cat', $from)/@count)"/>
    </point>
    <xsl:if test="$max > $to">
        <xsl:call-template name="summarize">
            <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$to"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input (corrected for well-formedness), the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <point from="0" to="100">3519</point>
   <point from="100" to="200">7638</point>
   <point from="200" to="300">4304</point>
   <point from="300" to="400">3216</point>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a simple template doing the count:

```
<xsl:template name="sum">
    <xsl:param name="from"/>
    <xsl:param name="to"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(//field[@tag >= $from and @tag &lt; $to]/@count)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Here you see the whole XSLT which output the sum of the fields having the @tag 0 to 100 and 100 to 200:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"></xsl:output>    

    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <sum_0_100>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                <xsl:with-param name="from" select="0"/>  
                <xsl:with-param name="to" select="100"/>                  
            </xsl:call-template>
        </sum_0_100>
        <sum_100_200>
            <xsl:call-template name="sum">
                <xsl:with-param name="from" select="100"/>  
                <xsl:with-param name="to" select="200"/>                  
            </xsl:call-template>
        </sum_100_200>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="sum">
        <xsl:param name="from"/>
        <xsl:param name="to"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//field[@tag >= $from and @tag &lt; $to]/@count)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives you this output:

```
<sum_0_100>3519</sum_0_100>
<sum_100_200>7638</sum_100_200>
```

Now you can use that inside your XSLT with the appropriate elements to be created

Comment: What if I want do dynamic to and from variable based on the highest number in file. Like if the highest is 801 then i will do the it 8+1 =9 times series.Is it doable?